# Trying to initialize Quill with specific formats and getting an error

Tags: quill

I am trying to load quill to only support certain formats according to the format API here: http://quilljs.com/docs/formats/

But whenever I add the format key I get the error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined`

Here is the code to initialize quill. If I comment out the format key, it works.

```
@editor = new Quill(@find('.quill-editor'),
      formats: ['bold']
      modules:
        placeholder:
          text: "Enter Text" 
          style:
            color: '#A9A9A9'
        'authorship':
          authorId: username
          enabled: true
        toolbar:
          container: @find('.quill-toolbar')
        "link-tooltip": true,
        #'placeholder': 'Enter Text'
        #'image-tooltip': true
      theme: "snow"
    )
```

What could be wrong. Why does quill not like the formats key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The likely culprit is the placeholder module (not sure if this is yours or a third party). Removing it fixes the problem and the `formats` config works as advertised: http://jsfiddle.net/b1s09v3n/.

A similar issue is on this [Github Issue](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/469). Since multiple people are running into this perhaps some part of the documentation is not clear? Or you are both using the same third party placeholder module.

Comment: thanks. I need a placeholder. and that was the only placeholder module I could find.